# explain preg_match syntax with #hash

Tags: preg-match

could you please explain what this preg_match code is doing!
I also don't understand why it starting with # tag?

```
if (!preg_match('#\.(.+)$#', $file['name'][$key], $matches)) {..;}
```

Comment: pcre lets you choose what character you want to delimit the pattern, that's all. in this case, it's `#foo#`, instead of `/foo/`

Comment: Hashtag is being used as a delimiter.